# Editing Lamp Strength with Python

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, node-editor, light

I am trying to animate changing brightness of a point lamp using input data that I have. However, when I try to access the lamp's strength using

```
bpy.data.node_groups["Shader Nodetree"].nodes["Emission"].inputs[1].default_value
```

I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Shader Nodetree" not found
```

Is there another way I can/should access and change the lamp's strength via Python?

Comment: you can find the answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92332/change-value-of-sun-light-emission-strength-from-python-console-or-script/141299#141299)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, reach node_tree through lamp object `bpy.data.lamps['lamp name'].node_tree.nodes.`

Comment: This works great! I'm now trying to add keyframes for the changing lamp strength, what should go in the `data_path` parameter?

Comment: My guess is 'default_value', since you keyframing a node input.