# Change value of sun light emission strength from Python console or script

Tags: python, materials

I need to programatically modify the value of sun light[image]

From the picture, it seems we can code it from

```
bpy.data.node_groups["Shader Nodetree"].nodes["Emission"].inputs[1].default_value = 1.2
```

however, the code produce an error that

```
>>> bpy.data.node_groups["Shader Nodetree"].nodes["Emission"].inputs[1].default_value = 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Shader Nodetree" not found'
```

I found a similar [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63288/change-value-of-material-emission-strength-from-python-console-or-script) it is related to changing the material, but mine question is related to the sunlight, how would i do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the tooltip can be a little misleading, look for the `node_tree` property on the lamp data object.

With the lamp as context object

```
>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Lamp']

>>> C.object.data.node_tree.nodes['Emission'].inputs['Strength'].default_value = 2
```

# or via bpy.data (D)

```
>>> D.objects['Lamp'] == C.object
True

>>> D.objects['Lamp'].data
bpy.data.lamps['Lamp']

>>> lamp = D.lamps['Lamp']

>>> lamp.node_tree.nodes['Emission'].inputs['Strength'].default_value = 3
```

Comment: I tried bpy.data.lamps['Lamp'].node_tree.nodes['Emission'].inputs[1].default_value = 100, but got error : KeyError : 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key 'Lamp' not found

Comment: Select your lamp object and type `C.object.data` into  python console.  If it prints `bpy.data.lamps["ItsCalledSomethingElse"]`  it won't respond the the name "Lamp".

Comment: oh, I understand. i tried it in python console, by typing C.object, it responds with bpy.data.objects['Sun']; by typing D.objects['Sun'].data, it responds with bpy.data.lamps['Sun.001'].

Comment: This is not working for me, C and D don't exist if you call blender from terminal with a python script `./blender -b -P ./myScript.py`

Comment: This helped me: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/39533/61307

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Select lamp

```
lamp_objects = [o for o in bpy.data.objects
                if o.type == 'LAMP']
lamp = lamp_objects[0] # assuming you only have one lamp
```

### 2. Set use_nodes to True

```
lamp.data.use_nodes = True
```

### 3. Set value

```
lamp.data.node_tree.nodes['Emission'].inputs['Strength'].default_value = 7
```