# Enable lamp 'Use Nodes' from python Console

Tags: python, scripting

I am new to both Blender and Python, I am trying to enable *Use Nodes* of a lamp from Python console.

I tried the tooltip showing on the button `bpy.ops.cycles.use_shading_nodes`, it did not give me an error, but also did not really enable the nodes(no change in UI), and I cannot change lamp strength using:

```
C.object.data.node_tree.nodes['Emission'].inputs['Strength'].default_value = 100
```

Comment: You can find the answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92332/change-value-of-sun-light-emission-strength-from-python-console-or-script/141299#141299)

Answer (score 2):

This is the python command used to enable **Use Nodes** and change a lamp strength

**Blender 2.79**

```
# enable Use Nodes
bpy.data.lamps["your_light_name"].use_nodes = True/False

# set strength, set the default_value to whatever you like
bpy.data.lamps["your_light_name"].node_tree.nodes["Emission"].inputs[1].default_value = 10
```

**Blender 2.8**

```
# enable Use Nodes
 bpy.data.lights["your_light_name"].use_nodes = True/False

# set strength, set the default_value to whatever you like
bpy.data.lights["your_light_name"].node_tree.nodes["Emission"].inputs[1].default_value = 10
```