# Custom Render Stamp, Principled BDSF values

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, shaders

I am trying to do a material study, and I would like to print the Principled BDSF values onto the render.

Previously I had found this:
[How to show render-stamp for arbitrary values?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26643/how-to-show-render-stamp-for-arbitrary-values)

It had worked, but the data path I get when I right click the *roughness* parameter for the Principled BDSF is:
`nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[7].default_value`

That doesn't seem to work the same way.

here is the script:

```
import bpy

def stamp_set(scene):
    note  =   "Samples: "                     + str(scene.cycles.samples)
    note += ", Bounces, Max: "                + str(scene.cycles.max_bounces)
    note += ", roughness: "                + str(nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[7].default_value)
    note += ", Version: "                     + bpy.app.version_string
    scene.render.stamp_note_text = note


bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.append(stamp_set)
```

I also tried, `cycles.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[7].default_value`

and

`scene.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[7].default_value`

I get an error in the terminal that these are undefined (I think).

SO, how would I go about doing this?

thanks,

eh five

Comment: I can't really tell, does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101929/getting-the-actual-not-default-value-of-a-node-socket-that-is-linked-to-anothe

Comment: I can't tell either, although the links in those questions did seem in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution with various references.  The big thing that helped was finding how to enter the value for a Principled BSDF parameter in the console;

```
bpy.data.materials['Material'].node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[1].default_value = 3
```

Mostly from here:

[Change value of material emission strength from Python console or script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63288/change-value-of-material-emission-strength-from-python-console-or-script)

The final script looks like this (input 7 is Roughness):

```
import bpy

def stamp_set(scene):
    note  =   "Samples: "                     + str(scene.cycles.samples)
    note += ", Bounces, Max: "                + str(scene.cycles.max_bounces)
    note += ", Roughness: "                + str(round(bpy.data.materials['Material'].node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[7].default_value, 3))
    note += ", Version: "                     + bpy.app.version_string
    scene.render.stamp_note_text = note


bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.append(stamp_set)
```

ref:

[Editing Lamp Strength with Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39532/editing-lamp-strength-with-python/39533#39533)

[Change value of sun light emission strength from Python console or script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92332/change-value-of-sun-light-emission-strength-from-python-console-or-script)

decreasing excess precision:

[How to show render-stamp for arbitrary values?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26643/how-to-show-render-stamp-for-arbitrary-values)

-snaok